# How to map a MySQL char(n) column to an instance variable using a JPA/Hibernate annotation?

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jpa-2.0

I encounter a JPA/Hibernate mapping problem on a column "language" in a MySQL table whose type is char(7). In my entity, the code generated for the field is:

```
    private String language;
```

this causes the following exception at runtime:

```
        ... 43 more
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: prosvetaPersistenceUnit] Unable to build EntityManagerFactory
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:911)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:74)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:225)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:308)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1477)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1417)
    ... 58 more
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Wrong column type in joo16_dev.jos_categories for column language. Found: char, expected: varchar(255)
    at org.hibernate.mapping.Table.validateColumns(Table.java:283)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.validateSchema(Configuration.java:1313)
    at org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaValidator.validate(SchemaValidator.java:139)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:378)
    at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1842)
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.buildEntityManagerFactory(Ejb3Configuration.java:902)
    ... 63 more
```

Thanks in advance !

JP

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Try this:

```
@Column(name="language",columnDefinition="char(7)")
```

see if that works.

Comment: Similarly, @Column(name="params",columnDefinition="text") for db column "params" of type text and @Column(name = "published", columnDefinition = "tinyint") for db column "published" of type tinyint Joomla! developers are familiar with.

Answer (score 1):

For me*Grails it's works: **sqlType: "char"** on mapping