# Hibernate String to char(32) mapping in MSSQL

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate

We have a schema in Microsoft SQL Server 2008 (already created) where is a table with a column of type `char(32)`.
We would like to map this to an entity property but it fails with a message:

> org.hibernate.HibernateException: Wrong column type in myTable for
>   column myColumn. Found: char, expected: varchar(255)

The dialect used is `org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2008Dialect` and the property is annotated with just

```
  @Column(name = "my_Column")
    public String getMyColumn() {
        return myColumn;
    }
```

The application won't be writing into database - it will be used read-only.

How can this be set to work? We tried `@Type` annotation with various values but without success.

EDIT:

It turned out that my real problem was `hibernate.globally_quoted_identifiers=true` property which made `columnDefinition` unusable and I thought that it isn't the right way to do the things. After being pointed to `columnDefinition` solution again I put more effort into finding out why it does not work for us and removing this property made it work for us as advised.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a `columnDefinition` to your `@Column` annotation.  See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6207788/how-to-map-a-mysql-charn-column-to-an-instance-variable-using-a-jpa-hibernate) answer.